# SSRS Expression builder to display two dates built in SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression

I have two dates to display in an SSRS text box showing a date range. I can build the syntax in SQL Server but I'm not able yet to figure it out in SSRS Expression Builder. Any clues?:

```
DECLARE @Start_Previous_Month DATE = DATEADD (mm, DATEDIFF (mm, 0, GETDATE ()) - 1, 0);
DECLARE @End_Previous_Month DATE = DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD (mm, DATEDIFF (mm, 0, GETDATE ()), 0));
```

I tried this but encountered syntax issues:

```
= "Date Range: " & DateAdd("m", (DateDiff("m", 0, Today) & - & DateAdd ("d", -1, DateAdd ("m", DateDiff ("m", 0, Today), 0))
```

Comment: `& - &` must be & " - " &

Comment: I was able to instead use the actual report fields but still syntax error but progress: = "Reporting Period: " First(Fields!Monthly_Report_Period_Start_Date.Value, "DataSet2") & - & First(Fields!Monthly_Report_Period_End_Date.Value, "DataSet2")

Comment: Reporting Period: 01/01/2023 - 01/31/2023     is how it's supposed to display.

Comment: the minus must be in quotes, else it will not be recognized as string

Answer (score 1):

```
= "Date Range: " 
+ Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Dateserial(Year(Today), 
Month(Today), 1)) , "dd-MMM-yyyy") 
+ " - " 
+ Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 0, Dateserial(Year(Today), 
Month(Today), 0)), "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

[image]